# eclipse for embedded c/c++ developers couldn't be launched on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: embedded-system, eclipse-cdt

I have installed eclipse for embedded c/c++ developers on Ubuntu 20.04, and it couldn't be launched the first time, but the next time, when I went to the installation directory, double clicked the icon, it was prompted:

[image: The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.]

and it hasn't made start menu entry and desktop shortcut even when I checked the 2 items when installation.

Comment: How exactly have you installed eclipse?

Comment: sudo wget https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/epp/2020-12/R/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz

Comment: and now I downloaded the .gz file, while after tar, it hasn't installer there.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:
first, I downloaded the wrong package, it should be "eclipse-embedcpp-2020-12..."
second, `sudo tar xzf eclipse-embedcpp* -C /usr/share`, then `sudo chmod +x eclipse`, then `./eclipse`